# Can I replicate a schema using flyway?

Tags: oracle11g, flyway

Can I replicate a schema using flyway from one environment to another.

Is it possible by one by one table or whole schema to replicate from Dev to Prod?

Comment: Why does your question title start with a period?

Comment: yes using placeholders: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/placeholder

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly share a set of migrations to be applied across multiple databases.

For example, you could have a structure:

`db/migration/
--V2_base_schema.sql
--V3_base_data.sql
--V4_change_table.sql
--R__function.sql`

as a resource bundle and provide the applicable runtime parameters to each environment in order to have the same migrations carried out on each database. Each database maintaining it's own `schema_version`, of course.

If you are asking if Flyway is the tool to somehow dump and restore, there is no such functionality - look to your databases native tools for that (eg `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` for PostgreSQL).